# Гиперпараметры нейронной сети

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Известно, что для сходимости нейронной сети регулируются такие параметры как:

- количество скрытых слоёв и их размер;
- момент и скорость обучения;
- нейроны смещения.

Известно также, что нет точной науки о их подборе. Используется метод проб и ошибок. 
Но, может есть способы наглядно оценивать по работе сети, какой из параметров и в какую сторону надо менять? Например, видишь что график изменения ошибки скачет вверх-вниз - надо уменьшить или увеличить скорость, или вроде этого. Поделитесь опытом, как вы изменяете данные параметры. Как оценивать в какую сторону менять параметры? Ещё нужны примеры их применения.